# How to set Jalali date to Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the Jalali date.

In Jquery Datepicker i have the function that set the today date.

```
$( "#divID" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

My question is, how can i set `$( "#divID" ).datepicker("setDate", new JalaliDate());`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

if I get right, you want to pick today's date in jalali.

and if you want a single date string, you can simply subtract `today-621` or `today-622` depending on what year you are.

but switching to today's date can not solve the jquery datepicker problem for jalali's dates.

here is some localized query for jalali and persian dates.

[jalali cal](https://github.com/farhadi/JalaliJSCalendar)

[jquery date picker supporting jquery-ui](http://hasheminezhad.com/datepicker)